# how do add serial numbers to a csv everytime something is appended?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-watchdog

I've built a file monitoring app using [`watchdog`](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) for new file additions. it appends some data about evey new file that's added to a csv in parent directory. I now also want to append serial numbers along with the data. how do i go about doing this?

here's what i now have:

```
with open("some_csv.csv", 'a', newline='') as fd:
    # i want to append auto incrementing serial numbers here
    fd.write(file_name)
    fd.write(file_size)
    fd.write(file_creation)
    fd.write(number_columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with pandas module, it is very easy.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep=',', header=None)
df.to_csv('test3.csv', index_label='index')
```

The above code will generage a csv named 'tes3.csv' with an auto incrementing column named 'index'

Answer (score 1):

You could use [UUID](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html):

```
import uuid

with open("some_csv.csv", 'a', newline='') as fd:
    fd.write(str(uuid.uuid1())
    fd.write(file_name)
    fd.write(file_size)
    fd.write(file_creation)
    fd.write(number_columns)
```

Comment: I want serial numbers. Not keys